# Laravel 4 Workbench Not Working On Pagodabox

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've created a workbench for my Laravel 4 application, and everything works as should on my localhost, but for some strange reason, when I push to Github, there's always an error saying:

> PHP Fatal Error: class Flashdp\Twittertag\TwittertagServiceProvider not found in /var/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 123

I don't know why this happens, but I imagine the auto loader is not finding the file. I don't know how to make Pagodabox see it. Any advice?

Boxfile contents:

```
web1:
  name: flashdp
  document_root: public
  php_version: 5.4.14
  php_post_max_size: "10M"
  php_upload_max_filesize: "10M"
  php_extensions:
    - mbstring
    - mcrypt
    - pdo_mysql
    - zip
    - xcache
    - curl
    - imagick
    - gd
  shared_writable_dirs:
    - app/storage/cache
    - app/storage/logs
    - app/storage/meta
    - app/storage/sessions
    - app/storage/views
    - public/storage
  after_build:
    - "if [ ! -f composer.phar ]; then curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php; fi; php composer.phar install --prefer-source"
    - "php composer.phar dump-autoload -o"
  after_deploy:
    - "rm -f app/storage/cache/*"
    - "rm -f app/storage/views/*"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you need to publish the package before you can use it. Workbench is for developing only

Answer (score 0):

Did you set you public folder on a boxfile?